# SELECT * from large table, or split table and make many small queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a personal project (browser based game) and a table that I use to store the player equipment that is fitted (weapons/armour and the stats for those items) on the db is currently 102 columns.

Every time I look at the table it bothers me that it is so big, but the page that uses it mostly needs all of the info there, so the user can see 'all their stuff'.

So I was thinking of normalising the table, but I am basically wondering if it is better to have a `SELECT * from table WHERE user = user`, on the big table, or break it into many smaller tables, and have many smaller queries, to gather the same info.

Or maybe there is a better way using joins, or other SQL wizadry?

If I were to split the table up, I imagine that I would end up with maybe 12 tables to replace the 1 big one, so I would have to make possibly 15 queries on the page if I hit all the tables with individual queries that I need. Is 15 queries a lot for a page if they are small and efficient?

Comment: All this talk about splitting up your tables makes no sense. There's only one way to normalize. Follow the normalization forms.

Comment: Table design is about normalizing data for scaling and eliminating redundant or missing data.  If for every column of the 102 there can be ONLY 1 relationship to the other data.. EVER... and no column is ever "NULL" then having 102 columns is fine.  If however, you have null columns or you could have more than one association to another entry, or another record could make use of similar data (say we change the name of an item does it update for each record?) if so, then you may want to consider normalizing the data.  Using a Join you can ge the SAME results as you would for 102 columns!

Comment: @xQbert, that should be an answer.

Comment: I realise the talk of 'splitting up' table makes now sense @Kermit, apologies, was thinking/typing out loud, and rambling a bit I guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database normalization is sometimes against performance of a selects, if you are joining data from more tables. On the other side normalization improve performance, if you need to insert, update or delete just some fields, because they are in smaller separate tables. But it's a good practice to design database fully normalized and then denormalize some parts to improve the performance if needed.

However, impact on performance is always very dependent on particular case: on data structure, predominant operations on that data etc.

Your table is an example of fully denormalized database. It's sometimes used as some sort of cache tables - normalized tables are still present, but there are also denormalized "cache" tables for faster selects.

It's really not a good idea to query each table separately, JOINs are well optimized to gather data from different tables.

It's always good to have as few queries required for one page as possible.

I think that good start to study normalization could be [Database normalization on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

---

In your case, I would consider to store equipment in a rows instead of columns. With that I mean to have basically 3 tables: *user*, *equipment* and *user_equipment*.

Table *user_equipment* would have just 2 columns: *user_id* and *equipment_id*, that means classic N to M relation. But it can also contain fields, which are specific for user and also equipment, that means for example *equipment_damage*.

Each equipment is one row in the *equipment* table (instead of column in the table *user_equipment*) and has its own ID. If you need to add new equipment, just insert new row to the *equipment* table instead of changing database structure (adding columns). It's much better manageable.

Also consider some **naming convention**. It's good practice to name tables in singular form and name N to M tables as conjunction of table names, which it connect together. Therefore tables *user*, *equipment* and *user_equipment*. If perfectly clear what they contain just from their names. You have the table *equiped_items*, which connects *users* and *equipment* or *items*, but you have to look inside to realize, what's inside.

Comment: "*Database normalization is usually against performance of a selects.*" Can you prove this?

Comment: Just a logical proof: the only reason for denormalizing normalized database is to gain performance. That means, that normalized database hurts performance some way. A saw a lot of systems with very normalized database containing a lot of denormalized "caching" tables.

Comment: Thank you for the link, hopefully it will refresh what I learnt in uni about normalisation, it was a bit of a blur in the first year...

Comment: It would be the best, if you understand what does it mean and how to use it, because there is no universal advice for normalization. It depends on particular data structure.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy hmmm, Well I have a user table, and an items table so instead of what I have now in my equiped_items table eg: user_id, sword_id, sword_name, sword_atk, ..... sheild_id, shield_name.. which is what got me to 102 cols, I should put each item as item_id on seperate row, linked to user_id? I think that might be what I need, as I can grab the stats from the items table etc

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Thank you, looking at the tables and functions involved, I think I can make things a lot better, for both the front end and back. Will have to rewrite a few functions, but should be better in the end.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy That's not a proof. The usual **reasoning** (not reason) for denormalizing normalized database is to gain performance. That doesn't mean it is justified. So, your argument is circular and not a proof.

Comment: @Reebo What for example *sword_id* contains now? ID of what? Why do you have *sword_name* there? Does it mean that if 10 users would have the same sword, there will be 10x the same sword name in that table?

Comment: @ypercube Ok, I can't prove it else.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy the issue is that you're talking like de-normalizing auto-magically improves performance. It certainly can depending on the type of workload you are looking to do. Looking to get into cubes you may want to consider de-normalizing. However if you're just de-normalizing to "increase performance" it's pretty much not going to work.

Comment: @Zane I wrote on multiple places, that it depends on a particular case. So I'll incorporate it to my answer too. Still I think it's well understandable from the first paragraph.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy yes there would be 10x the same sword name, which I realise is where I went wrong with this table, there is a lot of redundancy now I look at it with what people have mentioned here. The sword_id would be the item_id from the items table, which holds a record for every item in game. I guess I have been trying to keep queries to a minimum, and let some tables get out of hand. I may have to just spend some time sorting out the database now it has everything I need, it grew organically along with my ideas for the game, so I guess it's time for some normalisation.

Comment: @Reebo You don't need more queries even if you have more tables. Query with join(s) is still one query, which is better than two queries speaking about performance. Just move columns with redundant data in them to separate tables. Analogously as you have the *user* table, you should have an *equipment* table, where are data common for all "instances" of equipment. *user_equipment* should just join previous tables and add changing values, for example *equipment_damage*.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Thanks for your advice, it's helped me 'see the wood for the trees' so to speak. I do have a user and an equipment (items) table and my big table would be the user_equipment table, which holds much of the same info that is in equipment, so I see where I have redundant data. Comes from adding things as I need them really. I'll really have to have a good look at joins and brush up on my sql in general. It's all good fun :)

Comment: Great. So just remove redundant data from the *user_equipment* table and connect data in queries using join instead. I have updated my answer, hope it helps you a bit. Enjoy playing with SQL! :)

Comment: @DawidFerenczy thanks for the update, very clear. The 102 col table would be more like the equipped_items you mention, when a user equips an item eg: sword, the row assigned to the user_id would have the fields sword_id, sword_name etc updated to represent the data from the equipment table. The idea was to have all the fitted equipment represented in 1 table for easy access, so I could just select all from equipped_items and if a slot was empty, it would default to 'nothing fitted'. Looking at it now, updating an items stats, while users have them fitted would be a massive pain. Thanks again.

Comment: @Reebo I understand your initial intent, but as you said, it would be more pain than help :) You are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Well you should look into going to at least 3rd normal form. I find it likely a table as big as you claim it is contains redundancy. That is what will slow down your query, not adding joins.

Answer (score 5):

You should learn about normalization and how it can benefit you and your model.

SQL can easily handle JOINs.  If you have more than 7 of them in a query, you might want to break it up.

As a user, I doubt that I'd want to deal with multiple sets of 100 items at a time.  Perhaps you should think about how better to present the most important info and give uses the opportunity to drill into it.

Performance and efficiency are more likely to depend on good indexing.  If a column appears in a WHERE clause, you'd better have an index on it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of "better". From data redundancy, consistency and maintanability point of view, it's always best to have your data model in third normal form.
However, what's better from that point of view is not always better from the performance or code complexity point of view. My tip would be: start with a properly normalized DB and join queries. Denormalize if absolutely necessary because of measured and proven performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Well i think it depends on your UI. If all 102 items are needed at any given time, you won't get any performance boost splitting these tables. But, normalization is really a good way, because of redundancy, data inconsistency etc. On the other hand, if your UI is showing just part of these 102 columns, you should logically split this table to smaller tables with things they have in common. Then, you can simply integrate "on demand" request for data, if you really need them. Just keep in mind you must leverage performance of more HTTP requests vs. more data tranfered.

Comment: Thank you, I think lightweight query's as Marcus said, and a more on demand approach to the data from this table like you said might be the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Storing a lot of data in a single table isn't generally an issue.

You can make an expensive query against that table or you can make a lightweight one.

With such a large table (many columns), the following may be an expensive query, and you'll want to limit similar queries (even though the query cache may alleviate some of the expense).

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = 1
```

Here's a lightweight query against the same table:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname FROM user WHERE user_id = 1
```

Storing many one-to-one user attributes in a single table is fine. Only asking for what you need is the key here.

Searching (and the proper use of indexes) is generally a larger issue.

Comment: Thank you, I think you have given me an idea of how to make things better.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of great answers have been given but none mentions virtual tables also known as views. A view can be very useful in this case where information from essentially different entities(tables) is frequently fetched and displayed together.

Just normalize the database and then use a virtual table to collect all columns that are shown on that page into one view and then you can do one select on that view table.

You can learn more about views in this tutorial http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx or the reference manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html